# Escaping symbols from the json data

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

The problem is that I want to pass data to the vue component, I prepare a json data and use pass it as property.

```
<gallery-modal-edit
    :gallery='{!! json_encode($gallery) !!}'></gallery-modal-edit>
```

But vue writes in the console `'invalid expression:'`. So I think it is connected with the wrong symbols, which are stayed in json data. So what should I do with it? Is it normal to use extra param on the `json_encode` function on the php, or there is a simply way to find the solution for this problem?

The strings which cause problem look like this: 
`&quot;some text&quot; &lt;script&gt;`
`alert('xss test');&lt;/script&gt;`

**updated**
Simple example of php array:

```
$gallery = ['text' => '&quot;some text&quot; &lt;script&gt;alert('xss test');&lt;/script&gt;'];
```

Comment: can you share your json data and your attempt?

Comment: Look at the result of the encoding before you pass to view/template/whatever that is. I think whatever that step happens to be is escaping (htmlentities) the string.

Comment: `:gallery="'{!! json_encode($gallery) !!}'"` or `:gallery="'{!! @json($gallery) !!}'"` notice the quotes.

Comment: @sumit I've updated my post.

Comment: @ficuscr, so your advice to find some symbols, for example, single quotes and replace it before sending to blade template?

Comment: Hmm that array has invalid syntax. The `alert('xss test')` part ends the string. Wrap the string in `"` instead.

Comment: The only way which is working for me now is `json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP)`. But I think it's too dirty.

Comment: Don't use `:`. Just do `gallery='{!! json_encode($gallery) !}'`

Comment: @RoyJ , I dont know why, but this way doesn't work.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, this way doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [`v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) via the shorthand of `:`. It expects an expression. You are trying to pass a string. What Vue sees is like

```
:gallery="this is a string"
```

which is invalid syntax because Vue tries to interpret `this is a string` as an expression. You could quote it:

```
:gallery="'this is a string'"
```

and it would be valid, but it makes more sense to just do

```
gallery="this is a string"
```

Comment: Well, thanks to your answer, but it still works, only when I use extra options for `json_decode` function. And I think that this is connected with the single quote: if just write `gallery='{!! json_encode($gallery) !}'` it should fails on single quote, if it will not be escaped.

Comment: Yes, you would need to escape any quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to [laravel-news](https://laravel-news.com/blade-double-encoding-vue-components), the best way to solve this problem is to use double encoding:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

  public function boot()
  {
    Blade::doubleEncode();
  }
}
```